# Missing Cookie causing 401

Tags: web-services, iis, cookies, session-cookies, http-status-code-401

I am making a (forms)authentication module(HTTPModule) for IIS that reads authentication from the login page, sets a cookie and redirects. All works great on all sites and sub applications. Because the module also protects webservices I build in a part that also reads the authorization header. Because these services should also be accessed from other tools.

Now I got to the point I actually protect a webservice, all great and with the auth header to the request I can indeed always get to the webservice but I can ONLY access it with the header active(and after every request I get another cookie).

If I try to access it with my normal login, where I also access other sites under the same protection with then I get redirected back to the login page :S. I really do not understand why this is happening.

PS HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated is always false in my module when accessing the service, but my code is:

```
 if(!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated){
        if(Forms["Username"] != null){
          //do authenticatoin & setCookie and Principle
        }
 }else{
     if(AuthHeader is there){
         //do authenticatoin & setCookie and Principle
     }

 }
```

Naturally with every request now it authenticates and sets the principle for each request. But why oh why does it not see(send) my cookie while other applications do see it? (with the exact same module)

The OnAuthenticateMethod also does not receive the FormsAuth ticket/cookie but does receive other cookies I set.

Things I already checked:
* web.config authorization is correct.
* Machine keys are set for cookies.
* Cookie names are similar
* .ASPXAUTH cookie does not get send towards OnAuthenticateMethod, but it does get send by the browser in the Cookie header.

I am lost on why this happens.

Comment: It seems that the OnBeginRequest does not have HttpContext.User but does contain the cookie, but on OnAuthenticate the cookie is gone :S.

Comment: Been doing some manual FormsTicket.Decrypt and it seems somehow that webservice Application is not using the machine key :S